# Add to Calender link not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, drupal, calendar

I'm  trying to put a 'Add to Calender' link on my website but it doesn't seem to be working only on my website. Here is the link: https://www.cvrc.virginia.edu/content/test
You can see if shows up as a link and when you click it it doesn't have an add to option. Here is the code I used. If you open it up as a .html file on your computer it works fine. Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
 <head>
  <title>AddThisEvent</title>
  <meta name="Description" content="" />
  <meta name="Keywords" content="" />
  <meta name="Author" content="Michael Nilsson, AddThisEvent" />

  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <!-- AddThisEvent -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.addthisevent.com/atemay.js"></script>
<!-- AddThisEvent Settings -->
<script type="text/javascript">
addthisevent.settings({
    license   : "aao8iuet5zp9iqw5sm9z",
    mouse     : false,
    css       : true,
    outlook   : {show:true, text:"Outlook Calendar"},
    google    : {show:true, text:"Google Calendar"},
    yahoo     : {show:true, text:"Yahoo Calendar"},
    hotmail   : {show:true, text:"Hotmail Calendar"},
    ical      : {show:true, text:"iCal Calendar"},
    facebook  : {show:true, text:"Facebook Event"},
    callback  : ""
});
</script>
 </head>
<body>

<!-- Snippet -->
<a href="http://example.com/link-to-your-event" title="Add to Calendar" class="addthisevent">
    Add to Calendar
    <span class="_start">10-05-2012 11:38:46</span>
    <span class="_end">11-05-2012 11:38:46</span>
    <span class="_zonecode">40</span>
    <span class="_summary">Summary of the event</span>
    <span class="_description">Description of the event</span>
    <span class="_location">Location of the event</span>
    <span class="_organizer">Organizer</span>
    <span class="_organizer_email">Organizer e-mail</span>
    <span class="_all_day_event">false</span>
    <span class="_date_format">DD/MM/YYYY</span>
</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your page, the link actually links to "example.com" --

I imagine that your plug-in script is supposed to handle that, entirely -

So, you should put the script *after* the `<a>` - because if the script refers to things that don't exist in the DOM, yet - then it simply won't work.

Comment: Do you mean do this? <a title="Add to Calendar" class="addthisevent">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.addthisevent.com/atemay.js"></script>

Comment: yes - as well as the script block that comes after it -- It's generally good practice to put all the scripts you can (occasionally, some need to be in the <head> -- right before the closing </body> tag.

Comment: These two links have the same source but different results. Can you tell me what is wrong? http://training.cvrc.virginia.edu/applications/ https://www.cvrc.virginia.edu/otherscripts/index.html

Comment: Thank you i got it now. I needed to save the java script internally and use that instead to the external link.